# Autocomplete in CodeIgniter is not working (jQuery UI )

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

### jQuery code:

```
    $(function(){
      $("#birds").autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/codeigniter/learning/autocomplete"
      });
    });
```

### View:

```
    <label>Normal Autocomplete</label>
    <input type="text" id="birds" />
```

### Controller:

```
public function autocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->learning_model->get_bird_string($q);
    }
}
```

### Model:

```
public function get_bird_string($q)
{
    $this->db->select('bird');
    $this->db->like('bird', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('birds');
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
      {
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird']));
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); 
    }
}
```

this are the code i'm using for a normal autocomplete suggestion in textbox search the js files i am including in the view are:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

the problem is the code is not working. What i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost/codeigniter/learning/autocomplete directly in the browser?

Comment: can you check for any errors console after typing any thing in your textbox.

Comment: Does it sending any ajax request? check it at your browser console

Comment: there is no error in the console ... actually i have another set up for auto suggestion with images initially both (normal and with image) were working but now only the search with image works and normal one is not working any more

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error in your model function as [Num_rows](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) is a function not a variable so try it like,

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0) //num_rows() is a function
{
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
         $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird']));
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set); 
} else { // you can use elese part if no data found
   echo json_encode(array());// return json message
}
```